# Animation to Storyboard

Tags: ios5

I have this code.

```
UIImageView *sunrays = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,sunrays.frame.size.width,sunrays.frame.size.height)];
[container setClipsToBounds:YES];
[container addSubview:sunrays];
[sunrays setCenter:CGPointMake(container.bounds.size.width/2, container.bounds.size.height/2)];
[self.view addSubview:container];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:5];
CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation;
rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:M_PI * 2.0];
rotationAnimation.duration = 10;
rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 10;
rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
[sunrays.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

**It runs correctly in an application with .xib  file.**

The same exactly code with storyboard doesn't run.

I insert QuartzCore.framework and CoreGraphics.framework.
Where is the problem? Any help...?

Comment: Where is your code located? Soryboards create objects differently from XIBs, so if your code is in a wrong method, it is probably not called at all.

Comment: In viewDidLoad() method.

Comment: I FOUND IT. The problem was in the Interface builder. I had to change the class of my ViewController to the current ViewController class.